# Synchronized reactive chain with Reactor

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, project-reactor, reactor

I have the following reactive chain:

```
CacheMono.lookup(key -> this.retrieveFromCache(tenantId, key).map(Signal::next), carId)
    .onCacheMissResume(this.retrieveFromService(tenantId, carId))
    .andWriteWith((key, signal) ->
        Mono.fromRunnable(() -> this.carCache.cacheAndGetCar(key, signal.get(), tenantId)));
```

Everything works fine when only one request at a time is coming in, but if there are many requests coming in, retrieveFromService is called more than once.

How can I restrict, that only one request per tenantId can call the retrieveFromService at a time and the other requests work with the cached response of the first one?

Comment: How is this code called? As part of an HTTP request? One thing you might look into is Resilience4j bulkhead which lets you limit concurrency: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/bulkhead

Comment: Yes, it is part of an HTTP request and calls another API to retrieve information (retrieveFromService) to call the third API. I already use Resilience4j CircuitBreaker, I will take a look at bulkhead.

Comment: What might be tricky though is that you have to define some delay (maxWaitDuration) in the bulkhead, I'm not sure if the reactor version supports that or not. The ratelimiter one does support that.

Answer (score 1):

try to use lazy version: https://projectreactor.io/docs/extra/snapshot/api/reactor/cache/CacheMono.MonoCacheBuilderCacheMiss.html#onCacheMissResume-java.util.function.Supplier-

```
CacheMono.lookup(key -> this.retrieveFromCache(tenantId, key).map(Signal::next), carId)
    .onCacheMissResume(() -> this.retrieveFromService(tenantId, carId))
    .andWriteWith((key, signal) ->
        Mono.fromRunnable(() -> this.carCache.cacheAndGetCar(key, signal.get(), tenantId)));
```

or same but with lazy Mono.defer

```
CacheMono.lookup(key -> this.retrieveFromCache(tenantId, key).map(Signal::next), carId)
    .onCacheMissResume(Mono.defer(() -> this.retrieveFromService(tenantId, carId)))
    .andWriteWith((key, signal) ->
        Mono.fromRunnable(() -> this.carCache.cacheAndGetCar(key, signal.get(), tenantId)));
```

Comment: this does not solve the problem